# What is the proper way to type hint yaml files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

What is the proper way to type hint a yaml file?

The purpose of the function below is to check to see if a key exists. If it does, then I want to return that as a list and if it doesn't, then I want to return a NoneType. I successfully return `None`, but `typing` doesn't recognize that I am returning either `List[str]` or `None`.

```
import yaml
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List, Union, Any, Optional

def check_yaml(
        opts: Dict[str, Dict[str, Any]]
        ) -> Tuple[Union[List[str], None],
                   Union[List[str], None]]:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    if opts.get('Main', None) is not None:
        for sub_key in opts['Main'].keys():
            d['sub_key'].append(sub_key)
            if opts['Main'][sub_key]['name'] is not None:
                d['name'].append(opts['Main'][sub_key]['name'])
            else:
                d['name'].append(None)
            if opts['Main'][sub_key]['task'] is not None:
                d['task'].append(opts['Main'][sub_key]['task'])
            else:
                d['task'].append(None)
    else:
        d['name'].append(None)
        d['task'].append(None)

    return list(d['name']), list(d['task'])
```

I get the following error, and am not sure why.

```
Argument 1 to "append" of "list" has incompatible type "None"; expected "str"
```

Comment: Because you typed it as `List[str]`, which shouldn’t contain a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your type hint is saying that you are returning a tuple, of 2 elements, and these elements are either:

- A list of strings
- `None`

The difference is that you want a tuple, of 2 **lists** of either strings or `None`.

This translates to the slightly different:

```py
...
 ) -> Tuple[List[Union[str, None]],
            List[Optional[str]]]:
```

I put the two possible options for that, as `Optional[x]` is equivalent to `Union[x, None]`.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but mypy still doesn't like that I append ```None``` to a list.  I still am getting the same error.